# Як правильно зробити фонетичний розбір слова "футбол"?

Tags: фонетика

Як правильно зробити фонетичний розбір слова "футбол"?

Answer (score 6):

[Схема фонетичного розбору слова](https://web.archive.org/web/20161120123104/http://linguana.com.ua/ukrayinska-mova/fonetyka/shema-fonetychnogo-rozboru-slova.html):

1. Озвучити і написати слово фонетичною транскрипцією.
2. Поставити наголос.
3. Поділити слово на склади.
4. Визначити відкриті і закриті склади.
5. Назвати кількість звуків і кількість букв, вказати, чи відповідає кількість букв кількості звуків. Якщо такої відповідності немає, то пояснити її, вказавши, які букви позначають два звуки або не позначають жодного.
6. Назвати голосні звуки.
7. Назвати приголосні.
8. Вказати: глухі чи дзвінкі, м’які чи тверді приго­лосні.
9. Визначити фонетичні зміни, якщо такі є: чергуван­ня, подвоєння, спрощення, уподібнення.
10. Особливості вимови і правопису.

Відповідно до схеми:
***футбол***
`[фудб'ол ]`
2 склади, закриті
6 букв, 6 звуків

- ф - `[ф]` - приголосний, твердий, глухий
- у - `[у]` - голосний, ненаголошений
- т - `[д]` - приголосний, твердий, дзвінкий (глухі приголосні перед дзвінкими уподібнюються до парних їм дзвінких)
- б - `[б]` - приголосний, твердий, дзвінкий
- о - `[о]` - голосний, наголошений
- л - `[л]` - приголосний, твердий, дзвінкий (сонорний)

[Джерело.](http://subject.com.ua/textbook/mova/5klas/23.html)